# Does map.connect accept a wildcard-style format in the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

If I want to match **`x.gif` and `y.gif`**, is it possible to pass a URL to `map.connect` that encompasses the possibilities of both filenames something like this:

```
map.connect "public/images/:name.gif",
  :controller => "static_image_controller",
  :action => "serve"
```

And then receive the `param` in my `StaticImageController` as `params[:name]`?

```
class StaticImageController < ApplicationController
  def serve
    image_name = params[:name]
    image = File.read(File.join(Rails.root, image_name))
    send_data image, :type => "image/gif", :disposition => "inline"
  end
end
```

Besides the fact that what I am doing here violates the principles of convention over configuration in Rais, does this look right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
map.connect '/public/images/:filename', :filename => /\.gif$/
```

will do it.

Comment: What's the last part for? (:filename => /\.gif$/)

Comment: it says that for the route to apply, the filename parameter has to match the regex /\.gif$/