# Rails Routing with a parameter that contains a period

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

In older versions of Rails, you could have a parameter that includes a period (something typically reserved to separate it from the format) like this:

```
map.connect 'c/:domain.:format', :controller=>'home', :action=>'click_credit', :requirements => { :domain => %r([^/;,?]+) }
```

(nice tutorial [here](http://poocs.net/2007/11/14/special-characters-and-nested-routes))

However, in more modern versions of Rails (2.3.x) I'm seeing this fails - :domain is catching everything, and :format is blank when the request comes in for /c/amazon.com.html

Any ideas on how to modify it?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 3):

Upgrading to rails 3 should solve your problem. I tried your route in rails 3 and it worked fine (with a minor change to use the new routing syntax):

```
match 'c/:domain.:format', 
      :controller=>'home', 
      :action=>'click_credit', 
      :domain => %r([^/;,?]+)
# 'c/amazon.com.html' => domain: amazon.com , format: html
```

If upgrading to rails 3 is not an option, then this might help. Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029783/does-map-connect-accept-a-wildcard-style-format-in-the-url), I think the `:requirements` hash may be the culprit. Try this route and see if it works:

```
map.connect 'c/:domain.:format', 
            :controller=>'home', 
            :action=>'click_credit', 
            :domain => %r([^/;,?]+)
```

Comment: Were those two routes intentionally identical?  I'm finding it doesn't fly in 2.3.10 unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, all I did was to replace the `:requirements` hash. It's a strange bug because the routes parser is supposed to be smart enough to detect repeated patterns.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the domain into a slug and replace any [period] with a [slash].

The reason is because browsers expect . to define file type and you can not work around this.

Use [this gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/permalink_fu) to make it easy for you.

Comment: I don't think the browser has anything to do with this. It's a regular expression parsing problem because the `.` character appears twice.

Comment: I think @bowsersenior is correct.  A browser should not have any expectations of the file type based on the extension, and in fact most of us strive to keep extensions *out* of URLs.  The only reason I'm doing any this is to get page caching to work, because unfortunately in my setup Apache won't serve a static file as HTML otherwise.